# On the commutation with functions of operators in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, mathematical-physics, commutator, time-evolution

Given any complex analytic function $f$ defined on an open subset $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ of the complex plane containing the origin, for every linear self-adjoint operator $A\in{\mathcal{B}}(\mathscr{H})$ one can always define
$$
f(A) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {1}{n!}\frac{\partial^{n}f}{\partial z^n}\bigg\vert_{z=0}{A^n}.
$$

From this definition, it's therefore clear that

1. $\forall \operatorname{analytic} f:D\to\mathbb{C}\qquad $ $[A,f(A)]=0$ $\qquad$(it follows from $[A,A^n]=0 \quad \forall n$)
2. $[B,A]=0\implies [B,f(A)]=0$ and this implication is true $\forall$ hermitian $B\in{\mathcal{B}}(\mathscr{H})$.

**I'm wondering if these results remain true also for time-dependent operators**.

*E.g.* The evolution operator of a time-independent hamiltonian $H$ has the form $$U=\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}Ht\right)$$ and since $\exp(z)$ is analytical on all the complex plane, 1. and 2. hold.
In case of $H(t)$ though, the expression for $U$ is not that simple: $$\begin{aligned}U(t,t_{0})&={\mathcal  T}\left[\exp\left({\frac{-i}{\hbar}\int _{{t_{0}}}^{t}{d\tau\,H(\tau )}}\right)\right]\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac {(-i/\hbar)^{n}}{n!}}\int _{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{1}\int _{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{2}\cdots \int _{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{n}\,{\mathcal {T}}\left[H(t_{1})H(t_{2})\cdots H(t_{n})\right]
\end{aligned}$$ where $\mathcal T$ is called time-ordering operator (see [Dyson series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series)).

**Is it still true that $[H(t),U(t,t_0)]=0$?**

*Addendum*. In general, for a time-dependent Hamiltonian
$[H(t), H(t')]\neq 0$ if $t \neq t'$.
I don't know if this is of any help though, for in $[H(t), U(t,t_0)]$ both operators $H$ and $U$ are evaluated at the same time $t$.

Comment: It is not true anymore. In $[H(t),U(t,t_0)]$ both operators are evaluated at the same time $t$, indeed, but $U(t, t_0)$ is not a function of $H(t)$, it depends on all $H(t')$, $t_0 \le t' \le t$.

Comment: Did you try any examples?